# Method links does not exist in Laravel 5.6 app?

Tags: php, laravel, search, pagination, algolia

working with  laravel 5.6 and in My comtroller I have two tables like vehicles and uploads.relationship with  both  two tables are,
Vehicle Model,

```
public function uploads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Upload::class);
    }
```

and Upload Model,

```
 public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
    }
```

and I have following index function in My VehicleController,

```
 $vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
            ->orderBy('adtype','DESC')

            ->latest('updated_at')
            ->paginate(5);

            return view('vehicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
```

and index blade file is,

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ url('search') }}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <br> 

@forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )


                    @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp

                            <div style="border-style: solid; background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? '#FFEFD5' : '#FFFFFF' }} ">
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>


                        {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($vehicule->created_at)->diffForHumans()}} 
                            {{$vehicule->provincename}}
                          {{$vehicule->milage}}

                          </div>
<br>
                           <hr>

                    @endif

            @empty
                <td>No Advertisment to display.</td>
            @endforelse

</div>

</div>
</div>
{{ $vehicles->links() }}
</div>
@endsection
```

my pagination is working fine, but in my index file I have search input using algolia. when I use keyword and click search button following error is occured,

```
(2/2) ErrorException

Method links does not exist. (View: C:\Users\banda\Desktop\ddddd\resources\views\vehicles\index.blade.php)
```

when I remove {{ $vehicles->links() }} in the view file it is working.
how can fix this problem?

Comment: No any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
{{ $vehicles->render() }}
```

instead on ->links() ?

------ EDIT

Can you try passing the data to view like this?

```
 $vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
        ->orderBy('adtype','DESC')
        ->latest('updated_at')
        ->paginate(5);

        return view('vehicles.index')->with(['vehicles' => $vehicles]);
```

and check?

Comment: now got **Method render does not exist** error massage